# How to call a custom WebAPi Method from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call custom WebAPI method from MVC Controller but I am unable to achieve it. It throws error at mvcontroller.

MVCController.cs

```
 public List<Task> GetTasks()
    {

       string mystr = "http://localhost:55146/api/Tasks/GetTasks"; 
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(mystr);

            var camelCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            camelCaseFormatter.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Task>>(response.Result).Result;               
    }
```

WebAPI Method

```
public IQueryable<Task> GetTasks()
    {
        return db.Tasks;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't return your database model objects from an api action, this maybe what the error is relating to (post the error!). You should use Data Transfer Objects (DTO) to return the data from your action. Basically these are classes that have more or less the same properties as your DB classes then use Automapper to map one object to the other before returning. Also returning IQueryable is daft as you can't query the object over webapi, you'll want to return a List or even better IEnumerable, IQueryable should implemented IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning a collection of Task objects from the MVC controller, and not an ActionResult class? Shouldn't your API method return the JSON, and you MVC method return an ActionResult to view the list of tasks?

In any case, you should check that Task (in `List<Task>`) is not referencing the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` type, which is used to perform async methods.

Also, as mentioned, further information regarding the error message would be helpful.